# Milan Malpensa (MXP) to Firenze (Florence) direct train?

Tags: trains, italy

Is there a direct train or not and if there is, where can I book this mysterious thing? http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom-en doesn't show anything despite this https://www.italiarail.com/airport-connections rather official looking page claims there's now a direct train from Florence to the MXP airport: [image: Official pag]

The bahn.de website disagrees -- at least before noon there is nothing:
[image]

Comment: Your bahn.de image shows trains TO the airport, and it shows more than two before noon.  Any train that goes to the airport has to enter from the south, and leave the way it came (no tracks out the other side).  I find lots of high-speed trains from three different Milan stations to Firenze, but I don't think any of them are the airport station.  However, one of them is Garibaldi and there are frequent Metro from the airport to Garibaldi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the trenit app ([android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.baroncelli.oraritrenitalia&hl=en), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trenit-find-trains-in-italy/id1058908183?mt=8)), searching for trains from Malpensa to Firenze (all stations) and sorting by duration shows one change is required. I've tried several different days of the week and both Saturday and Sunday.

This 2010 [newspaper article](http://firenze.repubblica.it/cronaca/2010/09/10/news/treni_superveloci_da_firenze_a_malpensa-6955004/) says there was a direct train:

> DA Firenze, stazione di Santa Maria Novella, all’aeroporto di Malpensa
>   sul treno super veloce, senza mai scendere e cambiare
>   i.e. from FLorence Santa Maria Novella to Malpensa airport without having to change.

However, it was [suspended after less than two years](http://corrierefiorentino.corriere.it/firenze/notizie/cronaca/2014/29-gennaio-2014/progetto-moretti-treno-diretto-firenze-aeroporto-fiumicino-2223993513684.shtml):

> il precedente: il diretto da Santa Maria Novella a Malpensa è stato
>   sospeso dopo meno di due anni

Comment: AH! There we are. BTW I found a good flight from FCO and direct train there. We are all good :)

Answer (score 4):

Today and I suppose nothing changed for the last years (except the train availability at Malpensa for Terminal 2) all train connections are only to Milan train stations. There are no other trains, only Malpensa express and Trenord (which is regional Lombardy train system). No system will show to you "0 changes" because there are no such connections.

It means that you can travel only to Milan and, for example on main train station (Milano Centrale) you are able to get any other train to a destination you need to go to.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a direct high speed service in the past from Napoli Centrale, but the experimental line was ultimately abandoned after Expo 2015.

Today the only way to reach the airport by train is to change at one of Milan stations (for example [Milano Centrale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milan_Central_railway_station)) connecting long distance trains with **Malpensa Express** service.

Passengers from Lombardia region and Switzerland can benefit from the other local train services operating in MXP airport station.

Comment: This makes it sound like the Malpensa Express trains run non-stop between Milano Centrale and the airport, which is not the case. They make some other stops within Milano -- in particular at Milano Porta Garibaldi where a few long-distance trains (and many regionals) call.