# Best airport for Firenze?

Tags: air-travel, airports, italy, florence, flr

What alternatives exist to Firenze Amerigo Vespucci airport? It's a small airport with a very poor selection of destinations so better choices would be welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities:

1. Milan Malpensa. This a major hub, served from everywhere but there is [no longer a direct Frecciarossa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74322/4188) to Firenze. (Nor any other train as far as I am aware) so it takes 2:46 and a connection in Milano Centrale.
2. Rome Fiumicino. Even bigger selection, there are two direct frecciargento trains per day so catching one of them takes a little less than 2.5 hours.
3. Bologna Guglielmo Marconi. Many more destinations than Firenze but no transoceanic flights, there's a Dubai flight. There is no direct train but there's a [direct bus](http://www.appenninoshuttle.it/corse_linea_autobus_firenze_bologna_aeroporto_navetta.asp) which only takes 1:25. If you try to get to the bus stop from say the Stazione Galeria Ataf stop (ie the main entrance of the station where a billion Ataf buses stop) you need to walk the length of the train station *inside* along track 16, it's near impossible to cross Viale Filippo Strozzi if you are walking down Via Valfonda, there's a nice covered walking bridge and a ramp down the opposite side but there are no stairs going up on the station side from the street! Check Google Maps:

[image]

View from the street:

[image]

Also they are building the Marconi Express which will connect the airport with Bologna Centrale Station in 2019.

4. Pisa airport is ~an hour and with the new (March 18, 2017) automated PisaMover to Pisa central train station transit looks quite easy -- there's also a [direct bus](http://autostradale.it/en/airports/7/45/?lang=1). Huge selection of European destinations and Doha. Delta has a seasonal [New York-JFK](http://news.delta.com/delta-air-lines-launches-only-nonstop-summer-service-between-pisa-and-new-york) flight. At 2016 fall this is the only transoceanic flight within an hour of Firenze.

Comment: One of many reasons I left Tuscany as soon as possible to reach civilization: being a heavy turistic area we have the worst train connections, ridicolous highways, and the worst airports except for Pisa which is (or was), by the way, the one with the highest taxes in Italy so that a flight from there in respect to i.e. MXP was, at the times, up to 1000% higher.

Comment: Worth adding that there are at least hourly connections from Fiumicino to Florence when changing trains in Roma Tiburtina station. Also Terravision buses have a horrible track record on Pisa - Florence, when you run into trouble, cut your losses and take the train.

Comment: I'd also vote for the Rome Fiumicino, then take a train to Rome, and change to a high speed train to/through Florence.

Comment: Changing trains is a huge hassle with a suitcase. I'd rather not.

Comment: Pisamover is now up and running. Also the bus between Pisa airport and Florence seems to be no longer operated by Terravision (which was a nightmare, see my comment above) but by [Autostradale](http://autostradale.it/).

Comment: I book a flight to Firenze Amerigo Vespucci with a change of planes in Rome, bags are checked through. Otherwise from the Rome airport  taking a train to Rome and then a train to Florence is a hassle. I have flown in to Milan Malpensa, then a train to Milan then a train to Florence, a bigger hassle.